# Disabling fishing site warnings when auto-logging into HTTPS sites with UIWEBVIEW

Tags: xcode, security, url, uiwebview, warnings

I'm trying to figure out how to disable programatically the fishing site warnings that pop up when you enter a user name and password along with the url to a secure website, such as.

https://UserName:PassWord@Https://Secure.Website.com

Before the url comes up the warning dialog pops up first, since I know that the url I programmed is secure, I don't need the fishing site warning to pop up.

If anyone has any Ideas, I would greatly appreciate it. Thank you in advance.

Comment: If it was easy to disable these warnings programatically, they wouldn't be much use, would they?

Comment: What’s the reason for the uppercase title?

Comment: Instead of hardcoding username and pass in the url, can you store them in the user's keychain?

Answer (score 2):

You just cant do this.

This behavior is in private `UIKit` apis that you can't alter without being rejected from AppStore.

And for once, there is a good reason to this, a security reason :)

**EDIT** (after comments below)

I think you can disable these warnings in device settings : Settings App > Safari > Fraud Warning

[image]

Note that you can't do this with code from your app. You can only ask user to do so, or maybe by using Enterprise deployment facilities.

**EDIT 2** About security concerns

1. Again, there are very GOOD reason to this security, especially for a company concerned by its confidentiality/security.
2. It is not because you set a static URL in a `UIWebView` that this is the URL you will get, phishing is not only from websites servers, it can also come from a middle man attack on the TCP/IP connection, DNS spoofing, or who knows, an admin going nuts :)
3. Modifying private APIs is not easy, there is no source code, just assembly code that you can disassemble/analyze to figure a way to override/inject code doing what you want. It takes time that sorry I have not.
4. In other words : you should find an alternative solution, like another URL without https (ask webmaster) but another security, not requesting data from `UIWebView`... I'm afraid there is no easy workaround. And I guess you know that URL authentication like you are trying to do is highly unsecure, any intermediate could just get the query and login/password.
5. It is phishing and not fishing :)
6. Do you know you can edit your comments on stackoverflow?

Comment: Thank you Stack Overflow is amazing because of the number of well "USEFUL" information filled responses. No other site can math it. Thanks for the response.

Comment: Thank you. Stack Overflow is amazing because of the number of great informed responses. No other site can match it. Actually this application is not for the AppStore. Its an Enterprise App and is not released through the itunes mechanism. Because of this, the warning is a nuisance. The urls will never be fishing sites. They are pre-programmed & can never be changed. I just wished there could an off switch like the one in the Desktop Safari, namely the security setting "Warn when visiting... ect". That switch kills these warnings.Regards, and thanks again...

Comment: Thanks Vincent, yes it all makes sense (even the fishing). Thanks for taking time to respond and this is my first posting so the editing part i'm still getting accustomed to.  Regards.

Comment: Make sure to accept answers (green checkmark on left) and/or upvote if you find it relevant :)

Comment: @Alex Did you find any way to stop showing this warning? I have the same scenario, where the app is distributed by Enterprise mechanism and I am just showing a PDF file in `UIWebView`. So, there is no need to worry about security concerns.